# commas/ omitting "which is"

Tags: commas, omissibility

In the passage below, shouldn't the writer have included *which is* before the word ***championed***, since it is in a non-defining clause?

> In seeking to describe the origins of theater, one must rely primarily on speculation, since there is little concrete evidence on which to draw. The most widely accepted theory, ***championed*** by anthropologists in the late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries, envisions theater as emerging out of myth and ritual. The process perceived by these anthropologists may be summarized briefly.

Comment: "championed by anthropologists in the late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries" appears between a **pair** of commas and is parenthetical. Everything else is quite simple. HTH.

Answer (score -1):

No, a non-finite clause as well as a finite clause can be a supplementary clause (which is what you call 'a non-defining clause'). And if you're to use a finite clause there, it should be not *which is* but *which was*, because the supplementary clause is about *the late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries*.

> *The most widely accepted theory, **which was championed by anthropologists in the late nineteenth and early twentieth centuries**, envisions theater as emerging out of myth and ritual.*

### EDIT

Here are some of the many, many examples found in news articles and books:

> Tyndall believed it was vital for improving human health that the germ theory, championed by people like Louis Pasteur and Joseph Lister, be shown to be true.

(From [this Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/science/political-science/2018/may/22/what-would-a-19th-century-science-hero-make-of-todays-policy-world))

> The other dominant theory, championed by anthropologist Donald Symons in his 1979 book *The Evolution of Human Sexuality*, holds that the female orgasm, like male nipples, evolved as a byproduct of natural selection.

(From [this Quartz article](https://qz.com/981471/finally-a-feminist-case-for-the-evolution-of-female-orgasm/))

> The second major theory of our times is transformational leadership theory, championed by James McGregor Burns (2003), as well as by Bernard Bass and Bruce Avolio (1993).

(From the book [*What’s Wrong With Leadership?*](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=1CZxDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT228&dq=%22as%20well%20as%20by%20Bernard%20Bass%20and%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjH4srprafgAhXIbbwKHZEJAfUQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22as%20well%20as%20by%20Bernard%20Bass%20and%22&f=false))

Comment: See my comment at OP.

Comment: @Kris Saying that it "appears between a pair of commas and is parenthetical" is the same thing as saying that it's a supplementary clause. Then, why do you tell me to see your comment??

Comment: Because that's a much simpler and straightforward way to look at it.

Comment: @Kris How the mouthful, laymanish "appears between a pair of commas and is parenthetical" is much simpler and straightforward than the single, authentic term "supplementary"?

Comment: Thanks a lot, but some say that it's essential to include "which was" because it's in a non-defining clause, and it should not be omitted?? is that right?

Comment: Tell me who says that. Also, see my edit.

Comment: Mouthful, laymanish is **always** much simpler and straightforward. Get the facts. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris Just because you say so doesn't mean anything. Don't you ever use any grammatical terms from now on, if you can.

Comment: @JK2 Try not to advise unasked.